# How to link to a static member of a Java class in KDoc?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

In KDoc, you can do this:

```java
/**
 * [Integer.equals] is an instance method.
 */
```

But you can't do this:

```java
/**
 * [Integer.signum] is a static method.
 */
```

By "you can't" I mean that IntelliJ IDEA won't lead you to the declaration of a static member if you use *Navigate → Declaration* action on it. Navigating to static fields doesn't work as well.

Is there a way to link to static members of Java classes in KDoc? Is this probably just a bug in IDEA?

Comment: i think that's a bug, since the whole thing is not complited

Comment: Can you try now with current Kotlin, this should be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. It has been fixed in more recent versions of the Kotlin IntelliJ plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9946

Comment: It appears that KT-9946 has been marked as fixed, so this is no longer an problem?